# How to download and execute a .bat file from a php webpage

Tags: php

I forget the php code of that. Anyone help me please I want to download and execute a .bat file during webpage loading. Example: If someone open xyz.com when it's loading the page in during time a .bat file download and execute. Please help me to get complete code of that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: we don't "look" for code "for you". that's "your" job ,not ours.

Comment: You want that the user automatically downloads a .bat and that that .bat gets executed?

Comment: ...sounds fishy to me. `.bat` files can do "Lord knows what".

Comment: `@echo off del.` - Scary huh? Or maybe you don't know DOS; I do, as far back as DOS 5. Take a guess as to what that does.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Do you have a clue? on that ^ ^ ^ *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- My guess would be it deletes all files without prompting

Comment: @CharlotteDunois *Ouuuhhh*, you're good ;-) I'm curious as to how you would have "guessed" it. You didn't "Google" this, did you? *lol* haha! There are so many (dangerous) core (DOS) commands, it's scary. Which I might add, some are still part of the core Windows command file. I grew up on DOS 5. myself.

Comment: Well, I know that `DEL` is a delete command and then `.` could be a regex-like command saying "everything", and well, `@echo off` is super suspicious.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois The `@` (and `off`) just like most coding languages, is a suppressor/hides what goes on in the background ;-) That command however, has never made it into official documentation due to it being so dangerous if used for malicious purposes. I learned that one from a DOS "guru" way back when. He's still a "guru" to this day, just in higher places. Heck, nobody knows where he is now, and I grew up with the guy!

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.bat', 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init("http://filesite/file.bat));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);


    system("cmd /c ".dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.bat'");

?>
```

Comment: `("http://filesite/file.bat)` you missed a quote. Edit: did you run off somewhere? *lol* or you're going to leave it like that; erroring out.

Comment: ...I guess you're not going to bother then.